# Generate sitemap on a website made ​​with WebMatrix + Razor

Tags: razor, sitemap, webmatrix, auto-generate

I need to generate a sitemap to validate the site with Google Webmaster Tool.

How can I generate the sitemap for my website automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this sample:

```
@using System.Xml.Linq;
@{
    var urls = new List<string>{"home", "about", "contact"};
    XNamespace ns = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
    var baseurl = "http://www.domain.com/{0}";
    var sitemap = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XElement(ns + "urlset",
                from url in urls select
                new XElement("url",
                    new XElement("loc", string.Format(baseurl, url)),
                    new XElement("lastmod", String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Now)),
                    new XElement("changefreq", "monthly"),
                    new XElement("priority", "0.5")
                    )
                )
            );
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    sitemap.Save(Response.Output);
}
```

Save the file as Sitemap.cshtml. Obviously, you will need to replace the List with a source of locations for the map. But at least you can see how the XML is generated.

Comment: Thank you ... it was even needed!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is your best bet:

[ASP.NET MVC SiteMap provider](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/)

Read these pages:

[Dynamic sitemaps](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Dynamic%20sitemaps&referringTitle=Home)

[Exporting the sitemap for search engine indexing](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exporting%20the%20sitemap%20for%20search%20engine%20indexing&referringTitle=Home)

Comment: The site was developed in WebMatrix .. with Razor, as a provider of MVC can help? I do not understand.

Comment: @Riderman: no problem. Just register the provider and you can start using it. The documentation is right there in the homepage of the project at CodePlex.